# How can I write a SYSLOG message to different remote hosts in PHP?

Tags: php, syslog

How can I write SYSLOG messages to different remote hosts in PHP (v5.3.3)

I need to be able to specify the remote host at the time of the call, ideally with a parameter to syslog (or other message).

I don't see a host parameter in the syslog function.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php

I'm able to do this in some Java code, but for various reasons I need to convert to PHP.

Comment: I suppose to clarify:  IS there a way to specify a remote server to write a syslog message to in my code?  Not via a system-wide config.

Comment: Editted the initial question to describe the nuance.

Answer (score 0):

Just set error_log = syslog in your php.ini file and configure your local syslog daemon to send the requests somewhere else.